# I need help to write a macro or array to do the below exercise in SAS

Tags: sas

The data have five colums (ptid     start_dt    end_dt      regimen        duration.).[Data Set](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0SXcZnGAHMpbXlxVEZaTEdjWW4yY01teU1UM01jU0tBUkF3/view?usp=sharing)
I need to process this data in such a way that it will calculate difference between the start date of the next row and the end date of the previous row.If it is less than or equal to 90 days.Then it will check the regimen between next and previous row.If the regimen is equal or a proper subset to each other then this two rows will be merged..The new regimen will be the regimen which has greater duration .and the new start and end date will be minimum of this two merged row's start date and maximum of this two merged row's end date .It will continue to do so.
This exercise will be done by ptid wise. 
Any leads would be appreciated.
The data set is available in the shared link.

Comment: Please post what you've tried, what you expect as output from your sample data and your data in the question not externally. This problem, does not require a macro solution, a data step will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't easy to decipher exactly what you wanted, but try this as a simple way to get the correct date values in the same rows as each other.

if you do the following steps, you will have the correct dates saved as 'prev_date' and 'next_date' (provided your dataset is sorted as you wanted first) and then you will be able to apply your logic:

```
data __new;
set your_data_set;

    rown = _n_;
    rlast = _n_ - 1;
    rnext = _n_ + 1;

run;


proc sql;

Create table lagged as

    Select  a.ptid 
        ,a.start_dt 
        ,a.end_dt 
        ,a.regimen 
        ,a.duration

        ,a.rown
        ,b.start_dt as prev_date
        ,c.end_dt as next_date

from __new as a

left join __new as b

on a.rlast = b.rown

left join __new as c

on a.rnext = c.rown

;quit;
```